# realsense_dist runtime error

Tags: ros, realsense

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm using Intel Realsense R200 camera and [Realsense ROS SDK](http://wiki.ros.org/RealSense). When I run realsense_r200_launch.launch, I encountered following error.

```
[ERROR] [1446254837.488498054]: DSAPI call failed at /home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/src/realsense_ros/src/r200_camera_nodelet.cpp:509! status:  DS_FAILURE details: Internal exception: Failed to grab the Z frame hit return to exit
```

Any comment would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220194/realsense_dist-runtime-error/) by [Soonhac](https://answers.ros.org/users/225/soonhac/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2015-10-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you'd have a better chance of getting a response at [intel-ros/realsense/issues](https://github.com/intel-ros/realsense/issues) (apparently the 'official' repository for Intel Realsense support in ROS.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0